# How to cancel a completable future with cats effects 3

Tags: scala, completable-future, scala-cats, cats-effect

This code tests canceling a fiber created from a completable future and it is failing:

```
val toCancel = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { () =>
  Thread.sleep(20000)
  ()
}
val test =
  for {
    foo <- IO.fromCompletableFuture(IO(toCancel)).start
    _ <- IO.sleep(1.second)
    _ <- foo.cancel
  } yield toCancel.isCancelled

assertIOBoolean(test)
```

Is this a cats effects 3 bug, is there a work around?

Comment: I do not think so, completablefuture or any future runs on their own runtime, and cats effect do not have a hand in it, the future is only being embedded inside an IO. Take my advice with a grain of salt, I am not 100% sure

Comment: In the [documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/typeclasses/async) there is an example of wrapping a completable future into an IO with a finalizer that cancels it. However, it doesn't work since `stage.cancel(false)` is never called.

Comment: No matter what kind of async you are using this: `Thread.sleep(20000)` could at best be interrupted - which isn't the same as cancelling in Cats Effect! In CE cancelling is about telling IO that once current "step" ends, it shouldn't run another map/flatMap/etc. Since `Thread.sleep(20000)` is one giant step, there is no place for IO to cancel it. Making IO's cancel trigger CompletableFuture's cancel, which in turn could trigger exception could change the semantics where there are "atomic" operations.

Comment: I know it's not the same.  I expected that by canceling a fiber it would interrupt the underlying completable future. By looking at the cats effects 3 documentation you will find the following `//Cancel the completable future if the fiber is canceled
        Some(void(delay(stage.cancel(false))))`. What does that mean then?

Comment: Fiber's are not Thread's nor VirtualThreads. Fiber's are sequences of operations that run parallely - like Threads in Java BUT IO Fibers are actually run on thread pools, possibly sharing the pool with other computations. IO let you define a sequence of operations and they will be performed one after the other but any normal combination of IOs is still sequential. Fibers are used to make 2 IOs run in parallel (the interface provides: `start` (fork) and `join`). So this snipped you copy-pasted tells how IO's cancellation should be manually propagated to CompletableFuture.

Comment: I know what a fiber is. Looks like by applying cancel to the stage returned by handle is canceling the partial function that processes the results and not the completable future. I've just tried changing that and it works. So a bug I guess.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a bug.

It seems like you expect cats-effect to interrupt the `Thread.sleep` call, but I'm afraid that's impossible. A `CompletableFuture` is just a container for a result that will hopefully be available at some point in the future. It doesn't know anything about where that value might come from, or which thread is responsible for computing it or anything of the sort. It doesn't make sense to expect cats-effect to “interrupt the underlying completable future” (as you wrote in one of the comments), because a `CompletableFuture` isn't something that can be interrupted. It's merely a place to store a result in once it's available.
This is also why in the documentation of the cancel method it says this:

> mayInterruptIfRunning - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

If you want to create an `IO` that can be cancelled, you can't create it from a `CompletableFuture`.

You can try `IO.interruptible` instead, or `ASync.async`.

Comment: There is already a PR addressing this issue https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/pull/2665

Comment: Just be aware that even with that pull request, it's not going to interrupt the actual thread. You can easily verify that by adding a print statement right after the `Thread.sleep` call.

Comment: Thanks . I expect at least cancel to be called.